# Comparing elements from 2 string arrays in java

Tags: java, string

I have 2 String arrays say A and B.
both contains some strings. I want to compare array A with B to find the elements which are exist in both arrays.....

```
String[] a=new String[] {"alpha","beta"};
String[] b=new String[] {"alpha","beta","gamma","xxxx","yyyy"};
```

the result which I needed is alpha and beta...

Comment: Good luck and have fun! When you have an specific question that meets our guidelines, feel free to ask it. Check the FAQ, and look if a similar question has already been answered. Meanwhile, voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: [Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem**, and a **description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `retainAll` method from `Collection`.

```
String[] a=new String[] {"alpha","beta"};
String[] b=new String[] {"alpha","beta","gamma","xxxx","yyyy"};
HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
HashSet<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(b));
set1.retainAll(set2);
System.out.println(set1);     //Output : [alpha, beta]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the intersection of two arrays, you can have a look here : [Java, find intersection of two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863319/java-find-intersection-of-two-arrays).