# finding common elements in two integer arrays java

Tags: java, arrays

The code returns 0 and the common numbers more than once. I want it to return an array with the common numbers once! So how do I return an **array** with numbers that are common to both arrays. I want to return {2,7,4} - something like this. I keep getting out of bounds exceptions when I try to return an array.
Thanks,
Barry

```
public class Test {
    public int findCommonElement(int[] a, int[] b){
        int counter=0;
        int temp= 0;
        int tempCounter = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            temp=a[i];
            tempCounter=0;
            for(int j=0; j<b.length; j++){
                if (temp==b[j]){
                    tempCounter++;  
                }

            }

            if (tempCounter == 1) {
                temp = a[i];

                counter++;

                System.out.println(temp);

            }

        }

        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        int myArray[] = {2,2,7,7,2,1,5,4,5,1,1};
        int myArray2[] = {2,3,4,7,10};


        Test hello = new Test ();
        System.out.println(hello.findCommonElement(myArray, myArray2));

    }
}
```

Comment: it returns 0 because your method is set to returns 0

Comment: Multiple problems here. First, your function returns 0. Second, if you want to return more than one number you must change findCommonElement to return an Array or List.

Comment: Also, the counter variable in findCommonElement currently does nothing. Why does the if(tempCounter == 1) statement only check whether the tempCounter is 1? Should it not be if(tempCounter  > 0)?

Comment: Please indent you code properly — I have trouble reading it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java, find intersection of two arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863319/java-find-intersection-of-two-arrays)

Comment: thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the number of common element from the two elements will be dynamic. Hence if you try to put common elements into an array then it won't be possible as you need to declare size of this array (which in this case will be dynamic).

Consider using list. I've tried to keep the logic as simple as possible along with comprehensive variable names.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int myArray[] = { 2, 2, 7, 7, 2, 1, 5, 4, 5, 1, 1 };
        int myArray2[] = { 2, 3, 4, 7, 10 };

        Test hello = new Test();
        System.out.println(hello.findCommonElement(myArray, myArray2));
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param a
     * @param b
     * @return commonElements
     */
    public List<Integer> findCommonElement(int[] a, int[] b) {

        List<Integer> commonElements = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length ;i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j< b.length ; j++) {
                    if(a[i] == b[j]) {  
                    //Check if the list already contains the common element
                        if(!commonElements.contains(a[i])) {
                            //add the common element into the list
                            commonElements.add(a[i]);
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        return commonElements;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks nice simple solution!

Comment: Thanks Barry! Keep exploring!

Comment: @deFreitas I can think of O(n) solution, where I am use a hashmap for one array and while traversing other i just do map.containsKey() everytime.... I am trying to think if there is any better way to do that...other than creating O(n) space

Comment: This would be a very costly approach with `O(n*n)` complexity. Check out my solution with `O(n)` complexity and without the use of HashSets; thereby saving memory.     https://stackoverflow.com/a/67289502/6438896

Answer (score 7):

an alternative solution for `findCommonElement method`

```
public int[] findCommonElement(int[] a, int[] b){
    List<Integer> array = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int ele:a){
        set.add(ele);
    }

    for(int ele:b){
        if(set.contains(ele)){
            array.add(ele);
        }
    }

    int[] arr = new int[array.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size();i++){
        arr[i] = array.get(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: I think that solution is much better because has less complexity, is it `n+n+n` that is much better  than `nxn`

Answer (score 1):

here is an O(m+n) solution:

```
static ArrayList<Integer> commonElements(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> common = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while(true) {
        if (array1[p1] == array2[p2]) {
            common.add(array1[p1]);
        }
        if (p1 == array1.length - 1 || p2 == array2.length - 1) break;
        if (array1[p1 + 1] < array2[p2 + 1]) {
            p1++;
        } else {
            p2++;
        }
    }
    return common;
}
```

Comment: Are you considering both the arrays to be pre-sorted.

Comment: this is working only for sorted array.

int []array1= {2,3,5,6,7,9,11,22};
  int []array2= {22,2,4,5,6,8,10,12};
  ArrayList<Integer> list = commonElements(array1, array2);
  System.out.println(list);

Output : [2, 5, 6]

Comment: I've made some improvements in this and posted it.  Covers the edge cases. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/67289502/6438896

Answer (score 0):

I see the following issues with your code:

> I want it to return an array with the common numbers once!

So you need to declare that your method returns an array. Add square brackets:

```
public int[] findCommonElement(int[] a, int[] b) {
```

Inside your method you must also keep track of all common elements found so far. You may use a new array or more conveniently an `ArrayList` or even more conveniently a `HashSet` (since the set automatically eliminates duplicates so you get each common number only once). I think you meant the `counter` variable to keep track of the number of elements in the new array, only the array is not there yet.

You check:

```
if (tempCounter == 1) {
```

This is not right if the number occurs more than once in `b`. Instead do

```
if (tempCounter > 0) {
```

As I said, you need a way to filter away duplicates from `a` so you don’t get `[2, 2, 7, 7, 2, 4]` but only `[2, 7, 4]`. You may use a set I as I mentioned, or you may use `ArrayList.contains()` or introduce another loop to check whether the number is already in your array of common numbers. Just don’t add it again if it is.

Finally, to print the contents of an array, use `Arrays.toString()`:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hello.findCommonElement(myArray, myArray2)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

O(m+n) solution with the usage of Java Provided excellent Collection Data Structures. The key being `.retainAll()` function used in Hashset, which retains all the common elements:

It is worth mentioning that `retainAll()` works with any of the Collection class and internally calls contains() on it. Hence, O(m+n) will only be if the collection here is HashSet since it gives 0(1) lookup. If it is a linear one, like List, complexity will be 0(n^2)

```
public class common {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer[] arr1 = new Integer[]{1,1,3,4,6,6,7,2,2};
    Integer[] arr2 = new Integer[]{1,1,3,2,4,8,9,5,6};
    List<Integer> alist = Arrays.asList(arr1);
    List<Integer> blist = Arrays.asList(arr2);

    HashSet<Integer> aset =  new HashSet<>(alist);
    aset.retainAll(blist);

    System.out.println(aset);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int arr1[] = {1,2,5,7,89,3};
    int arr2[] = {1,45,87,34,3};

    for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<arr2.length;j++) {
            if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                System.out.print(arr1[i] +" ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, a few words of explanation will help current and future readers understand your answer even better.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove Complexity Using HashSet**

**Finding common elements in two integer arrays in java**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Complexity
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    int arr1[] = {2,2,7,7,2,1,5,4,5,1,1};
        int arr2[] = {2,3,4,7,10};

        HashSet<Integer> hashset= new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (int i : arr1){
            hashset.add(i);
        }
        for (int i : arr2) 
        {
            if (hashset.contains(i))
        {
            // found duplicate!   
                System.out.println("Common Elements --> " +i );
        }
       }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple O(n) solution that takes into consideration that arrays are sorted. If not, you can sort them. This is an improvement of the solution provided by @talshahar that also covers the last element being common(an edge case).

```
public List<Integer>  getCommon(int[]array1, int[] array2){
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> common = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(p1<array1.length || p2<array2.length) {       ​
       ​if (array1[p1] == array2[p2]) {
           ​common.add(array1[p1]);
           ​p1++;p2++;
       ​}
      ​
       ​else if (array1[p1] < array2[p2]) {
           ​p1++;
       ​} else {
           ​p2++;
       ​}
   ​}
    return common;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity o(n) i.e. using single for loop to get the common elements in an array.

```
    int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 5, 5, 8, 9, 7, 10 };
    int[] arr2 = { 1, 0, 6, 5, 6, 4, 7, 0 };

    System.out.println("Array1 : " + Arrays.toString(arr1));
    System.out.println("Array2 : " + Arrays.toString(arr2));

    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
        if (arr1[i] == (arr2[j])) {
            System.out.println("Common element is : " + (arr1[i]));
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Output:

```
Array1 : [1, 2, 5, 5, 8, 9, 7, 10]
Array2 : [1, 0, 6, 5, 6, 4, 7, 0]
Common element is : 1
Common element is : 5
Common element is : 7
```

Answer (score -1):

> int x[] = {5, 3, 7, 2, 8};
>           int y[] = {6, 3, 8, 0, 2, 7, 4, 9};

```
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
            if (x[i] == y[j]) {
                System.out.println(x[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
It is recommended to add a brief explanation of your code, which goes a long way in helping others understand it.