# Is there an array_intersect() equivalent in java?

Tags: java, php, arrays

I want to find the first repeated character from a string. I usually do it using `array_intersect` in php. Is there something similar in Java?
For example:

```
String a=zxcvbnmz
Desired output : z
```

Comment: What do you actually need to get those values for?  Maybe we can answer that question.

Comment: Been trying to learn java and there's this question to display the first repeated character in a string. It's rather simple in php. Is there an inbuilt function I could use to simplify the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**array_intersect** — Computes the intersection of arrays ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php))

---

So in this case you can use [**Set::retainAll**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) :

```
Integer[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
Integer[] b = {2,4,5,6,7,8,9};
Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a));
Set<Integer> s2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(b));
s1.retainAll(s2);

Integer[] result = s1.toArray(new Integer[s1.size()]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

**Output**

```
[2, 4, 5]
```

---

You can read about this here [Java, find intersection of two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863319/java-find-intersection-of-two-arrays)

Comment: Ive upvoted sir. This is totally legit. Idk why its downvoted

Answer (score 2):

There's no default implementation for this behavior; however, you can code your own solution! Since you want to find the first *repeated* character, you can make a `HashSet` of `Character`s. As you iterate through the array, you add each character to the `HashSet` until you come across a character already in the `HashSet` - this must be the first repeated character. Example code below:

```
public char arrayIntersect(String string) {
    HashSet<Character> hashSet = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        char c = string.charAt(i);
        if (hashSet.contains(c))
            return c;
        else
            hashSet.add(c);
    }
    return null;
 }
```

This runs in O(n) time, as `HashSet` lookups run in O(1) time.