# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException when add three array in excel

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

***UPDATE3***

Here I am getting all contacts of user phone and whatsapp number. after successfully retrieving I am getting IndexOutOfBoundsException.

***Code***

```
Map<String, String> namePhoneMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Cursor phones = getContentResolver()
            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null, null, null);

    // Loop Through All The Numbers
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {

        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        // Cleanup the phone number
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("[()\\s-]+", "");

        // Enter Into Hash Map
        namePhoneMap.put(phoneNumber, name);

    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : namePhoneMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Log.d("Login", "Phone :" + key);
        String value = entry.getValue();
        Log.d("Login", "Name :" + value);
        phoneContacts.add(key);
        nameContacts.add(value);
    }


    phones.close();


//ArrayList for Store Whatsapp Contact
Map<String, String> whatsappMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

final String[] projection = {
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
        ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
        "account_type",
        ContactsContract.Data.DATA3,
};

final String selection = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " =? and account_type=?";
final String[] selectionArgs = {
        "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.profile",
        "com.whatsapp"
};

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = cr.query(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        selection,
        selectionArgs,
        null);

while (c.moveToNext()) {
    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID));
    String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3));
    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

    Log.d(TAG, "name " +name + " - number - "+number);

    whatsappMap.put(name, number);

}
Log.d(TAG, "Total WhatsApp Contacts: " + c.getCount());

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entryWhatsapp : whatsappMap.entrySet()) {
    String key = entryWhatsapp.getKey();
    Log.d(TAG, "PhoneWhatsApp :" + key);
    String value = entryWhatsapp.getValue();
    Log.d(TAG, "NameWhatsApp :" + value);

    myWhatsappContacts.add(value);
}



c.close();
```

Till Now my code is working very well. Now I am adding a code of adding three array in excel file.

```
String csv = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SendingContactList2.csv"); // Here csv file name is MyCsvFile.csv

        Log.d("Login3", csv);
        CSVWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));

            List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
//            data.add(new String[]{"number","name"});

            for (int i = 0; i < phoneContacts.size(); i++){
//
                if (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(phoneContacts.get(i).length())) < 10) {
                    Log.d("Login34", String.valueOf(phoneContacts.get(i).length()));
                    phoneContacts.remove(i);
                    nameContacts.remove(i);
                } else {               
                    data.add(new String[]{phoneContacts.get(i),nameContacts.get(i)});// Line no 1


//                data.add(new String[]{phoneContacts.get(i),nameContacts.get(i),myWhatsappContacts.get(i)}); // Line no 2
}
            }

            writer.writeAll(data); // data is adding to csv

            writer.close();
//            callRead();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now when I run Line 1 code and when I run Line 2 It gives me Index out of bound exception.

Comment: Are you looking to find the intersection of arrays?

Comment: Possible duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java)

Comment: @user3401493 yes bro

Comment: Check following thread. its actually duplicate.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863319/java-find-intersection-of-two-arrays

Comment: thank you bro @user3401493 and please upvote it to prevent to reduce my reputation

Comment: @user3401493 Can you see my updated question

Comment: @AdisheshKishore can you see my updated question

Comment: @BlackBlind it will be better if you paste your code here.

Comment: @user3401493 Can you see my new updated question

Comment: you basically answered your question. The third array is shorter than the rest, so there is an example scenario ->  you try to get  5th element of this array but it has only 3 elements. So what is your question then ? How to get rid of this? You would have to rebuild the logic or provide some values to replace null if trying to get element which is not in bound of the third array

Comment: @P.Juni can you print araay1 and array2 in excel file programatically and in array2 put 0 instead of null

Comment: not sure what is your goal but see my update

Comment: you can also reduce this parsing in the if condition to just -> phoneContacts.get(i).length < 10

Answer (score 2):

1:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

    for(String s : array2) {
        if(Arrays.asList(array1).contains(s))
           System.out.println(s);
    }
```

2:

```
    for(String s2 : array2) {
       for(String s1: array1) {
          if(s1.equals(s2)) {
            System.out.println(s1 + ", " + s2);
          }
       }
    }
```

**UPDATE2**

```
if (phoneContacts.get(i).length < 10) {
    Log.d("Login34", String.valueOf(phoneContacts.get(i).length()));
    phoneContacts.remove(i);
    nameContacts.remove(i);
} else {
    String phone = phoneContacts.size() - 1 < i ? phoneContacts.get(i) : "0";
    String name = nameContacts.size() - 1 < i ? nameContacts.get(i) : "0";
    String third = thirdarray.size() - 1 < i ? thirdarray.get(i) : "0";
    data.add(new String[]{ phone, name, third }); 
}
```

Comment: Instead of looping through first array, loop through second array which is small in size would be better. Update your answer

Comment: can you explain else condition

Comment: this code showing this error  Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 200, Size: 200 on else condition third line

Comment: Else condition -> we check if the size - 1 of the array is smaller than the i variable, if so, then take value from array at position i, if not then take "0". But it’s just a blind guess. Post whole code